# Excel 2007 Pivot Table, Different Formulas in Different Columns

Tags: excel-2007, pivot-table

Created a Pivot Table in Excel 2007, and it seems I can only make it do one type of calculation at a time.

Is it possible to provide an average in one column, and a sum in the next?

When I click on "Value Field Settings", choosing any of the options applies it to every column in the Pivot Table, can't figure out how to apply it to only one column.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a different calculation.

When you drop a field into the data section of the pivot change the calculation to sum.

Then drag the same field across again this time change it to average